# Angular project build with Cannot Get / error

Tags: css, node.js, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I tried to run my Angular in IntelliJ and got this error. When I open the browser on localhost it shows `Cannot GET /`

The steps I took were:

- Open up the project
- npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
- gradlew clean build
- ng serve

```
ERROR in ./src/novus-rego-theme/theme.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/
sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-3!./src/novus-rego-theme/theme.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import 'node_modules/@angular/material/theming';
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  C:\Users\paul.d\1 - PROJECTS\simple-reg\reg-ui\src\novus-rego-theme\theme.scss 1:9  root stylesheet
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

Does anyone had the same issues?

Here's my `theme.scss` file:

```
@import 'node_modules/@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue.
$app-primary: mat-palette($mat-light-blue, 400);
$app-accent: mat-palette($mat-light-blue, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$app-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$app-theme: mat-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent, $app-warn);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($app-theme);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify `@import 'node_modules/@angular/material/theming';` as below.

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
```

Comment: It works! I can open my project on the browser now. Thanks mate. Do you know why I get this oauth error though?

Comment: [HPM] POST /oauth/token -> http://localhost:8090
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /oauth/token from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:8090 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/erro
rs.html#errors_common_system_errors)

Comment: Are you now facing this error? This is an another issue. I suggest you to post a new question.

Comment: Yes, it's the same project. Just realized I got this error. Will post a new question.